# Setting the HornetQ Embedded-Remote Example

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

I am having some troubles setting the example in the [hornetq-2.3.0.Final jar](http://downloads.jboss.org/hornetq/hornetq-2.3.0.Final-bin.tar.gz) under the core folder named Embedded-Remote, I am trying to run the example in a "remote enviroment" using for this two computers in the same LAN,   if i run the two classes without changing anything in the same computer "EmbeddedRemotExample.java" runs ok, but as this example lacks configuration files I am not sure about how to set this class to connect to a server running in another computer. reading the api I found that this was a valid code:

`

```
     HashMap map = new HashMap();
     map.put("host", "192.168.XXX.XXX");
     map.put("port", 5445);
     ServerLocator serverLocator = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(
         new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(),map));
     ClientSessionFactory sf = serverLocator.createSessionFactory();`
```

but this produces the next exception

```
HornetQException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=HQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:852)
at org.hornetq.core.example.EmbeddedRemoteExample.main(EmbeddedRemoteExample.java:49)`
```

How could i set this specific example to work?

in one computer :             org.hornetq.core.example.EmbeddedServer

in other one :                org.hornetq.core.example.EmbeddedRemoteExample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the same configuration to the server's Acceptor at `EmbeddedServer.java`. As by default it would be set to localhost.

I reckon that that example needs a code clean-up:

https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/pull/1062

This specific commit would make clear what you need to change:

https://github.com/FranciscoBorges/hornetq/commit/fbed7e8394c843e4528df90d4c2ef155a7d032c0

Comment: Exactly what i needed, Thanks a lot for the fast answer and git commit.